# How to inject into a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, dependency-injection, broadcastreceiver, dagger

Does someone already had to inject an already existing class, with some business logic, into a BroadcastReceiver using dagger?

I'm using dagger 1 and already found a nice example (https://github.com/adennie/fb-android-dagger) but, I could not find how we can add an already existing class, which belongs to a different module, into a BroadcastReceiver.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to inject use cases into my Broadcast by defining a Module which provide the use cases I need and I add the Module on the onReceive method, check the code below:

My **BroadcastReceiverModule**:

```
@Module(injects = { MyBroadcastReceiver.class }, addsTo = MyAppModule.class)
public class BroadcastReceiverModule {
    @Provides @Singleton MyUtilsClass providesMyUtilsClass(MyUtilsClassImpl myUtilsClass) {
        return myUtilsClass;
    }
    @Provides @Singleton MyUseCase providesMyUseCase(MyUseCaseImpl myUseCaseUtils) {
        return myUseCaseUtils;
    }
}
```

My **BroadCastReceiver**:

```
@Inject MyUtilsClass myUtilsClass;
@Inject MyUseCase myUseCase;
@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AcidApplication.getScopedGraph(getModules().toArray()).inject(this);
    myUseCase.call();
    myUtilsClass.doSomething();
}
protected List<Object> getModules() {
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(new BroadcastReceiverModule());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Note - this is Dagger 1.

Answer (score 31):

**Dagger 2 example for injecting objects into a BroadcastReceiver.**

The BroadcastReceiverModule.kt

```
@Module
abstract class BroadcastReceiverModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributesMyTestReceiver() : MyTestReceiver
}
```

The AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = [
            (AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class),
            (BroadcastReceiverModule::class)
        ])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApp> {
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<MyApp>()
}
```

The Application class

```
class MyApp : DaggerApplication() {
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<MyApp> =
            DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this@MyApp)
}
```

The BroadcastReceiver class

```
class MyTestReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var anInjectedObject: MyInjectObject

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this, context)
        anInjectedObject.doSomthing()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do this in 2019. However, you can save the last two steps by simply having your Application class extend `DaggerApplication` and your Receiver extend `DaggerBroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @s-hunter is it also possible to define the `BroadcastReceiverModule` as an `interface`? Could you please explain why did you choose an `abstract class` for this? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 29):

Same as you inject to an Activity

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ((Application) context.getApplicationContext()).getInjector().inject(this);
    }
```

Comment: Are we guaranteed that Application Context will always be an Application instance? If not, this is not an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 23):

It might be too late to answer this question, but I will provide an example from my recent project where I tried to inject `AppWidgetProvider` which is a direct subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`.

We need to inject a retrofit service into a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
@Module
public class NetModule {
    /** shrunk for simplicity's sake. **/
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public WidgetService provideWidgetService(Application application, OkHttpClient client, Gson gson) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(application.getString(R.string.api_url))
                .client(client)
                .build()
                .create(WidgetService.class);
    }
}
```

Create another abstract `@Module` for the with abstract methods annotated with `@ContributesAndroidInjector` that return `BroadcastReceiver`s you want to inject:

```
/**
 * To inject the app widgets.
 */
@Module
public abstract class WidgetsModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract IngredientsWidget contributesIngredientsWidget();
}
```

If you forgot to add this module, you will get error like:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for
>   Class<>

Then the component with both modules, besides [`AndroidInjectionModule`](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.10/dagger/android/AndroidInjectionModule.html)

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, NetModule.class, WidgetsModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(RecipesApp recipesApp);
}
```

Then in your `Application` class you implement `HasBroadcastReceiverInjector` interface.

```
public class RecipesApp extends Application implements HasBroadcastReceiverInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<BroadcastReceiver> broadcastReceiverInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        component().inject(this);
    }

    public AppComponent component() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<BroadcastReceiver> broadcastReceiverInjector() {
        return broadcastReceiverInjector;
    }
}
```

Finally, you can inject your  BroadcastReceiver inside onReceive() before calling the super().

```
public class IngredientsWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Inject
    public WidgetService api;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /** Don't forget this line **/
        AndroidInjection.inject(this, context);
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

}
```

You can find more about how to inject android components [docs](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html).

I built a small sample: [broadcast-injection](https://github.com/amrro/broadcast-injection).

Comment: Any Idea how to test that ?

Comment: That's the kind of Stackoverflow answers I like: explanation with examples, link to the docs and a example project on GitHub - thanks @amrro !

Answer (score 5):

just a little too late but I have a slight improvement over the previous answers, you don't need to explicitly call `AndroidInjection.inject(this, context);` in `onReceive` method.

Here is the receiver so you don't have to do that, the trick is extending from `DaggerBroadcastReceiver`:

```
class MyReceiver : DaggerBroadcastReceiver() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var repository: MyRepository

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        // Do your stuff...
    }
}
```

The rest is just the same registering the modules, etc. I hope it helps :D

Answer (score 4):

You can use DaggerBroadcastReceiver or you can override onReceive method like below:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this, context);
    // your code should be here ...
}
```

dagger documents: 
https://dagger.dev/api/2.24/dagger/android/DaggerBroadcastReceiver

Answer (score 1):

- Previous solutions don't work anymore now in the latest Hilt versions as Hilt does not have any function called AndroidInjection.
- App Widget Provider extends the Broadcast Receiver. So you can simply annotate any Broadcast receiver like this:

Answer:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class StandardWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var room: AppDatabase

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In KOIN Dependency Injection,

```
class ServiceClass1()
class LazyServiceClass2()
```

// In Activity no need for KoinComponent

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    // evaluates dependency eagerly
    val service: ServiceClass1= get()
    
    // evaluates dependency lazily
    val lazyService: LazyServiceClass2by inject()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
             
        // does something with services
    }

}
```

But In the case of Receiver, extend "KoinComponent" like below

```
// In non-lifecycle component, KoinComponent is needed
class SomeBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver(), KoinComponent {
    
    // evaluates dependency eagerly
    val service: Service1 = get()
    // evaluates dependency lazily
    val lazyService: LazyService2 by inject()
    
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        // does something with services
    }

}
```

Hope it will work for you.